# Gallery not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a photo gallery on a website: http://www.firstaidlifeline.co.uk/gallery/. 
However, no images are displayed on the website.

I believe the problem lies in the CSS (or JS), since the HTML looks good to me.

The HTML looks as follows:

```
<div id="flickrGal0" class="justified-gallery">
    <a href="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5813/22733190139_f81bfe7a9b_b.jpg" rel="flickrGal0" title="20130213_153547"><img alt="20130213_153547" src="https://farm6.static.flickr.com/5813/22733190139_f81bfe7a9b_m.jpg" data-safe-src="https://farm6.static.flickr.com/5813/22733190139_f81bfe7a9b_m.jpg">
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="photo-title photo-title-with-desc">20130213_153547</div>
        </div>
    </a>
    ...
    ...
    ...
</div>
```

The html by itself works elsewhere. So I think there is a conflict somewhere in the JS or CSS somewhere however, I'm unsure exactly where.

Comment: Can you post the JS and CSS code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up the source code, and the library. `justifiedGallery.js` file isn't loaded in the page. Function `fjgwppInit_flickrGal0()` that calls `justifiedGallery()` isn't called; this explains why the console doesn't fire up any error. Load `justifiedGallery.js` in the `<head>`

Put

```
jQuery(function(){
   fjgwppInit_flickrGal0();
};
```

Somewhere on your page.

#### Edit

It seems the gallery is generated by a plugin, I presume you should play the settings, or, the plugin could be damaged. [Plugin homepage](http://codecanyon.net/item/justified-image-grid-premium-wordpress-gallery/2594251)